# Client Certificate and HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, certificate, windows-server-2003

I have two keys

a .PEM-file and a .KEY file.
The pem key is in X509-format.

I have got the the pem-file from a provider (I have sent to the provider the .csr).

I am about to send a client certificate by using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes in Microsoft Visual C# .NET.

For that I have registret the pem-file at the 2003-windows-server by using the mmc-tool in windows:

1) Click Start, click Run, type mmc, and then click OK.
2) On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.
3) In the Add/Remove Snap-in dialog box, click Add.
4) In the Add Standalone Snap-in dialog box, click Certificates, and then click Add.
5)   In the Certificates Snap-in dialog box, click Computer account, and then click Next
6)  In the Select Computer dialog box, click Finish.
7)  In the Add Standalone Snap-in dialog box, click Close, and then click OK.
8)  Expand Certificates (Local Computer), expand Personal, and then click Certificates.

I have then imported the pem-file (also with mmc).

The Question is:
How do I give permission to the certificate?

I have tried this (WinHttpCertCfg.exe tool):

```
winhttpcertcfg -l -c LOCAL_MACHINE\Root -s NON-Production.pem
```

And what about the .key-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It is a n application built on top of openssl that will help you make a p12 file from your .key-file and .pem-file. It is simple. Import .key-file on **Private Keys** tab. Import .pem-file on **Certificates** tab. Then on **Certificates** tab export the certificate as PKCS#12 (combo box **Export Format**). Set a password if you wish or leave blank. Then you can import this .p12 file using mmc as you wrote.

Now you can use winhttpcertcfg to set permissions on private key. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation will help you. (parameter -s means subject. In mmc open the imported certificate and look for CN=**something** in the subject field. Then add this **something** with -s parameter).

Comment: It looks interesting. I will try that. 
maybe you can help me further.
I have basicaly this curl from a company, that has to be converted to .NET.

curl -k  -v -X GET "https://FIRMA.com/api/Status?q=AAA&userId=BBB" --cert recieved_key.pem --key myselfgenerated.key 


After I have done what you describe, will the next step then be use this command sending a https-request carrying the new .p12-file?
     X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("d:\\cert\\abc.p12");

something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28395/Attaching-a-digital-certificate-public-key-to-an-H

Comment: It should be used this way `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("d:\\cert\\abc.p12", "Password");`. If you have blank password then use empty string as password.

Comment: Everything works perfectly well now. I am very grateful. Thanks a lot.